# Is this lens too heavy for my micro four thirds body?

Tags: lens, micro-four-thirds, weight

This is the setup I'm planning to use: Camera is an Olympus OMD E-M10 II, the lens is a Bower 500 mm f/6.3 using a Bower T mount to micro four thirds adapter.

The cause for my concern is that I plan to mount this on a tripod, which requires putting the camera on the tripod, since the lens does not have a tripod mount on it.

This in turn means the camera has to support the entire weight of the lens: about 1 lb 6 oz.  If it's necessary for getting an answer, I'd estimate the center of gravity of the lens is between 3 and 4 inches from the mount.

Am I safe mounting this lens on the camera body, and then placing the camera on a tripod?

Comment: Would disagree with the "duplicate" assessment: The setup intended has many potential problems that are not about damaging or wearing out the lens mount. However, if (as I suspect) the 500mm f6.3 you are talking about is a catadioptric, you'll probably be fine. If it is a non-telephoto long lens with the given specs, the tripod head could yield or break (ITWC crashing the camera)!!

Answer (score 1):

Lens mounts are fairly sturdy things - but why risk it when the good people at manfrotto make [these](https://www.adorama.com/bg3420.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiA2NXTBRDoARIsAJRIvLzxkk0ZwVH2JXMnbWCboqWP6UMgf6hAH9FsqAj9Qk83ZGDyYz8AX5caAnXZEALw_wcB)?

[image]

I can't comment about the particular lens and body combo - but I will say that adding the adapter adds an additional weak point. So, I think you're better off not chancing it and getting something like the linked item to add some telephoto support.